# How can one solve integrals like $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{1+{e}^{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried the elementary rules, but could not solve it. I also tried using the complex numbers method $(\cos x+i\sin x)$, but was unsuccessful. Is there a method to solve specific integrals like these?

Comment: Goto Wolfram alpha & type integral_{0}^{pi/2} cos(u)/(1+exp(u)) du ... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bpi%2F2%7D+cos(u)%2F(1%2Bexp(u))+du ...

Comment: this integral can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I did that, but the answer turns out to be much more complicated than my limited knowledge of. Hoping to get a more intuitive approach here.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks for the review. Is there any approach towards questions like these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One may obtain an analytic expression. By integrating by parts twice, one has
$$
\int_0^{π/2} e^{-n x} \cos x \:dx = \frac{n+e^{-n\pi/2}}{n^2+1}, \quad n>0,
$$ then one may expand the integrand and integrate termwise to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{1+{e}^{x}}\:dx&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{1+{e}^{-x}}{e}^{-x}\:dx
\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\int_0^{π/2} e^{-n x} \cos x \:dx
\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{n+e^{-n\pi/2}}{n^2+1}
\end{align}
$$ and the latter series may be expressed in terms of special values of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) and in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.14) function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Olivier, though may I ask how did you obtain that summation from the integral in the third step?

Comment: @ChetanPandey You are welcome. I've used $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}e^{-n x}=\frac1{1+e^x}$ and I've used the very first identity.